# Script running fine in FF fails to run in IE

Tags: java, selenium

I am using Selenium Webdriver(Java), i want to use IE driver for my testing, however i come up with the problem, can anyone help me out of this please, The script which are running fine in firefox fails to run in IE, I am just opening a google page and searching some word but my code only opens the google page write the keyword but unable to hit the serch button on google page using IEdriver, after too much google i found one thimg that when IE browser get opens it will opened in IE8 Compatibility view and due to this its attributes like id, name get changed as compared to FF, but when i changes this to IE8 view manually the properties are same as FF,(Press F12 key on keyboard open developers tool on IE) So can anyone please let me know how to overcome this or how to open the IE browser in IE8 mode, or anyone knows any different solution of using IE for selenium webdriver.
My code is as follows

```
package backOffice;  
import java.io.File;  
import org.openqa.selenium.By;  
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;  
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;  
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;  
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;  
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;    
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.BrowserName;    
import bsh.ParseException;  

public class Time    
{   
   private WebDriver driver;    
   private String baseUrl= "http://www.google.co.in/";      
   public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException   
  {                 
     Time tm=new Time();        
     tm.trial();    
  }     

private void trial() throws InterruptedException    
 {          
    File file = new File("C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/32-      bit_IEDriverServer_Win32_2.31.0/IEDriverServer.exe");        
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
    DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();                caps.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);        
    driver=new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);        
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/");                          
    driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).clear();         
    driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).sendKeys("harshal kakade");          
    driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfb")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Harshal Kakade - India | LinkedIn")).click ();      
  }  
 }
```

Thanks,

Harshal.

Comment: Maybe this can help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804714/selenium-ie8-force-ie8-compatibility-view

Comment: You should really try this against something that isn't Google. Google's markup is pretty complex, for instance I get *entirely* different ID's on the elements you are using.

Comment: Hi Arran,

I tried with other web also same is the behavior observed for me.

Thanks,
Harshal.

Comment: Anyone to help me out this...Plz

Answer (score 0):

try to look at the internet options -> security and uncheck "Enable Protected Mode". Probably there is the problem.