# How to force compatibility view

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have IE 11 installed, but I need to run a few tests in IE 8, 9, & 10 as well. How can I force the compatibility mode when running a test.
FYI, I did try F12, and set the mode to 8. It works manually, but not through selenium.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into exact same issue recently. Unfortunately, there is no way unless you change page source. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804714/selenium-ie8-force-ie8-compatibility-view). However, I can tell you what I have done. I used VMS of course. Luckily, microsoft also provides trial versions of VMS with different versions of IE. visit [this](https://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads). After getting the VMs ready I installed [NUNit Console](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=download). I then simply copied and loaded the test `dll` on that and just run.

Comment: Nice!. your answer definitely is very well explained. Going to give it a try :) Thanks!

Comment: @familyGuy the set up was little tricky. Let me know if you face any issue