# How to add web sites in compatibility view list using any webdriver in IE 11

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, internet-explorer-11

I know that there are webdrivers (Selenium, Microsoft webdrivers for IE) which exposes APIs to modify web pages and possibly minimize or maximize browser window.

Is there any API from any webdriver which can modify/add web sites into compatibility view list by going through "Tools->Compatibility view settings->Add this Web Site->Add" ?

I want to achieve this on IE 11 using any programming language, preferably using C#.

Answer (score 0):

No there is not. Selenium does not provide any mechanism to force browser to change the compatibility at this moment. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29420506/how-to-force-compatibility-view) how I am handling this. Virtual machines with NUnit console probably the easiest way to handle the compatibility. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804714/selenium-ie8-force-ie8-compatibility-view) can be helpful for you.

Comment: Yeah... I was looking at some standard API from any web driver which can operate on Internet Explorer menu items...

Answer (score 0):

[Modern.IE](https://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools) is a good alternative, since Selenium doesn't support what you are asking.