# selenium - internetexplorerdriver compatibility mode

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, nunit, compatibility-mode

Is there any way how to force webdriver/internetexplorerdriver to open a site in compatibility mode. Every time I run my tests by Nunit all the history and compatibility mode list (where was my site listed before) are cleaned.

I can't change the code of the site. Can I add item to compatibility mode list or open site in specifi version of IE (I have 11 and I need open it in 7 with doc type 5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is better description of my issue: I need to test a site that I can't edit. The site works only in compatibility mode in my IE 11 (it is made for ie 7 doc type 5). I want to run tests and cookies should be cleaned before that. But if I set "EnsureCleanSession = true" it cleans compatibilty list in IE besides cookies. Because of it, it's not possible to test the site.

I have found possible solution, but I have to test it...  I've found out that compatibility list is in registry and I can load its value before it is cleaned and set the value again:

```
        const string keyName = @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation\ClearableListData";     
        var a = Registry.GetValue(keyName, "UserFilter" , "Return this default if NoSuchName does not exist.");
        // value of registry is removed
        Registry.SetValue(keyName, "UserFilter", a);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

But as I said, I don't know if it will do the trick...

**[UPDATE]**

Ok, it works with small work-around (because IE must be restarted after change in registry)

```
    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        //read the compatibility mode list from registry
        const string path = @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation\ClearableListData";
        const string key = "UserFilter";
        var regValue = Registry.GetValue(path, key, "Return this default if NoSuchName does not exist.");

        //run IE driver with cleaning of cookies and history
        var options = new InternetExplorerOptions
        {
            IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true,
            EnsureCleanSession = true
        };
        _driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(IeDriversPath, options);

        //cloase IE
        _driver.Quit();
        _driver.Dispose();

        //put the compatibility mode list back into registry 
        Registry.SetValue(path, key, regValue);

        //run IE driver without cleaning of cookies and history
        options.EnsureCleanSession = false;
        _driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(IeDriversPath, options);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, unless you change the source code. As a workaround I use VMS. If you want to use the same route consider [using free VMs from Microsoft](https://www.modern.ie/en-us). See my another answer related to question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29420506/how-to-force-compatibility-view/29420797#29420797)

Comment: I've red your previous answer where you refer to another answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804714/selenium-ie8-force-ie8-compatibility-view . I wanted to assure myself, that there is no option except VMs. To be more specific, I have problem with "EnsureCleanSession = true" that clear my compatibility list. If he didn't do that everything would be fine for me :/

Comment: What you have issue with? Cookies?